# Call custom field using php

Tags: functions

```
function the_alt_title($title= '') {
    $page = get_page_by_title($title);
    if ($p = get_post_meta($page->ID, "_x_entry_alternate_index_title", true)) {
        $title = $p;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_alt_title', 10, 1);
```

My theme uses something called `alternate index title` and I also have the above custom function in my `functions.php`

I presume the `alternate index title` is recognised as a custom field in wordpress?

How can I call the `alternate index title` using php code on a page?

Comment: You are using `get_post_meta()` to get the custom field value. You can use the same function in any WordPress template file, including pages. Where do you have the problem?

Comment: hmm.. i think I need to create a custom shortcode, because the php code is not rendered on the page

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Yes, you need to create a shortcode to render some php as template part to show inside a page content. The name of custom field must be the same; avoid the usage of _x_entry on **get_post_meta()** if you know exactly the name field is alternate_index_title

Comment: ok but why should I do that? I got it to work based on thedeadmedic said ? do you have a better answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

```
<?php $index_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_x_entry_alternate_index_title', true ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the alternate index title inside the content of your page then you will have to create a custom shortcode. You cannot use PHP in the post's/page's content area, but you can use shortcodes.